# Parallel reduce algorithm implementation

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I've been investigating implementations of reduce [inject, fold, whatever you want to call it] functions in Objective-C using blocks and was wondering if there were any techniques for parallelizing the computation where the function applied is ***associative*** (e.g. sum of a collection of integers)?

i.e. is it possible to parallelize or improve on something like this on NSArray:

```
- (id)reduceWithBlock:(id (^)(id memo, id obj))block andAccumulator:(id)accumulator
{
  id acc = [[accumulator copy] autorelease];

  for (id obj in self) {
    acc = block(acc, obj);
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Using grand-central dispatch?

EDIT: I've made a second attempt, partitioning the array into smaller chunks and reducing them in separate dispatch queues but there's no discernable performance gain in my testing: [(gist here)](https://gist.github.com/1099122)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [dispatch_apply](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_apply.3.html) with Dispatch Global Queue for parallelizing it, but your code seems that it is not so efficient with concurrent work. Because the accumulator object requires exclusive access, and it is tightly used by the block, thus it will cause giant lock for the accumulator object.

For example, this code is nearly non-concurrent work even though using dispatch_apply with Dispatch Global Queue.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
dispatch_queue_t queue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_apply([array count], queue, ^(size_t index) {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    acc = block(acc, [array objectAtIndex:index]);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
});
dispatch_release(sema);
```

You need split the block and the accumulator implementation for efficient parallelization.

**EDITED:**

(I haven't check the algorithm of your code.)

```
dispatch_queue_t result_queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL);
```

You are using Serial Queue. Serial queue executes one block at a time. Thus, it might be

```
dispatch_queue_t result_queue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

or

```
dispatch_queue_t result_queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
/* DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT is only available OS X 10.7/iOS 4.3 or later. */
```

Comment: Thanks, I've pursued this already. dispatch_apply didn't seem to like it when I reassigned the value of acc and semaphores just slowed the whole thing down. My general pattern above can be found in several libraries on Github. I was wondering if there are any known algorithms (in any language) which can execute this in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT constant, I hadn't read the updates to libdispatch in Lion and I'm getting a ~45% speedup which seems reasonable.

Comment: Great man! This was the best answer about Parallelism that I found here.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a parallel divide & conquer algorithm which works with associative functions [here](https://gist.github.com/1101546). Unfortunately I couldn't get any discernable speedup from it so I'm sticking with a simple serial version for now. I believe my base case needs optimising- I read somewhere that the inequality `n >= p^2` should hold, where n is the number of jobs and p the number of processors.

Obviously a lot of time is being lost on array-splitting and recursing, if anybody has suggestions they'd be much appreciated.